# C++ modularization framework (like OSGi) ?

Tags: c++, boost, frameworks, osgi, modularization

I found one SOF http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/SOF_.aspx ,
Are there anyother stable frameworks for modularization in C++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OSGi4Cpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osgi4cpp/) tries to implement the OSGi specification in C++.

Comment: osgi4cpp is a dead project - never had any activity on it.

Comment: indeed, this is the least usefull of all the answers to this question

Answer (score 5):

The authors of the open source Portable Components library (POCO) have also developed a modular framework based on OSGI called OSP or Open Service Platform. http://www.appinf.com/en/products/osp.html.  It's not open source however.

Answer (score 5):

I found this write-up which gives a status as of April 2012. Definitely worth reviewing
[OSGi and C++](http://blog.cppmicroservices.org/2012/03/29/osgi-and-c++/) frameworks overview.

Answer (score 4):

There is also BlueBerry http://www.blueberry-project.org which implements a component based framework inspired by OSGi. It also comes with an application framework similar to the Eclipse RCP.

A rewrite of the BlueBerry core can be found in the CTK PluginFramework library (based on Qt Core): [Introduction](http://www.commontk.org/index.php/Documentation/CTK_Plugin_Framework:_Introduction), [GitHub Code](https://github.com/commontk/CTK) .

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen a solution to the whole problem, but I implemented something similar using [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) plugins.

The part Qt did nicely (that C++ by itself doesn't implement) was handling C++ OO interfaces in dynamically loadable modules.  Because of C++ name-mangling being non-standard, usually DLLs don't have C++ interfaces, only C interfaces.  Qt did it with it's meta-object system, and it worked really cleanly for me.

Comment: the [CTK Plugin Framework](http://www.commontk.org/index.php/Documentation/Plugin_Framework) uses the QT plugin system, as is described in the blog post that @Langley linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [cppmicroservices](http://cppmicroservices.org/). It is actively developed and provides a reasonable starting point for creating an SOA based dynamic services in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Celix is an OSGi implementation for C and C++
http://celix.apache.org/