# c++ -- how to implement a framework that supports plugins

Tags: c++

As we know, Eclipse is a good framework that supports plugins based application development. I am using c++ for coding and would like to learn how to build a framework that support the plugins development. One good example is the Notepad++ that supports plugins. Is there a good book or resource that I can refer to.

Thank you

Comment: You might want to look at another SO question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627114/c-modularization-framework-like-osgi

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a pretty good overview of how one could do it: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2015.pdf

Beware that this proposal is for a generic plugin framework for the C++ language.  For your particular application, you may not need all the described features.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it's kind of an over kill answer (it has good points). Maybe you should first read about interpreters:
http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/interpreter.html

You then should decided the boundaries of your plugins and script language, maybe you should start reading about the spirit module in boost.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider just loading shared objects (linux) dynamically, with predefined function hooks...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *handle;
    double (*cosine)(double);
    char *error;
    handle = dlopen ("libm.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }
    dlerror();    /* Clear any existing error */
    cosine = dlsym(handle, "cos");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf ("%f\n", (*cosine)(2.0));
    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

The above was stolen from [dlopen(3) Linux page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen), but it illustrates an example, where `libm.so` can be the module, and `cos`, could be the function name that your hooking to. Obviously this is far from a complete module / plugin framework.... but its a start =)